# Skype voice repetition

Tags: skype, alsa

I use Skype 4 with ALSA.

People tell me that they hear my voice twice (voice and the echo of it).

To make it clear, I don't hear my voice from the speakers.

It is Skype which sends my voice twice to my interlocutor.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What happens in skype call test?

Comment: The same what others was telling me. I hear that my voice is doubled.

Comment: do you have a microphone on your computer and plugged in?

Comment: I have an external microphone.

Comment: can you a) record yourself on sound recorder, does that double?

Comment: No, I don't hear a doubled voice in a recoded written by arecord

Comment: apparently we should be discussing this in chat 0_0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4444/discussion-between-user14416-and-joshua-siret)

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to try MX Skype Recorder
http://skyperec.com/ which is stable and fulfills its duties. Well, at least it never let me down. Hope it'll help.